# After casting json data to [[String: AnyObject]] it seems to be empty - why?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm calling my webservice with `alamofire` and trying to parse the json result.

My code looks like this:

```
Alamofire.request("\(serverURL)/users/\(username)/hashtags")
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
switch response.result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                print(response.result.value!)

                if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        print("this is not printed")
```

The first print returns:

```
{
    hashtags =     (
        test,
        elo
    );
}
```

and the 2nd one is not printed at all - the code is never executed. Why?

When I call my webservice in the browser I'm getting:

```
{"hashtags":["test","test2"]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON structure you are trying to convert is a dictionary not an array. You are trying to convert the response to an *array of dictionary* and that's why it is failing.

You need to use:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject]
{
   // Handle data
}
```